# Are all even numbers the difference of prime powers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, diophantine-equations, perfect-powers

Does there exist an even positive integer greater than $100$ (to eliminate trivial cases) that cannot be expressed in the form:

- $p^2-q$
- $p-q^2$
- $p^2-q^2$
- $p^3-q^3$

where $p$ and $q$ are primes.

Comment: Do you only want to represent the number in one of these $4$ cases or are you okay with $p^n-q^m$ for arbitrary $m$ and $n$?

Comment: And, in light of Batominovski's answer, you should perhaps express more clearly whether you want each number expressed in at least one of these forms, or in all of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For sure, there are infinitely many even integers that cannot be written as $p^2-q^2$ where $p,q$ are primes.  You only have to look at integers of the form $4k+2$ (or $8k+4$), where $k\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Also, there are infinitely many even integers that cannot be written as $p^3-q^3$.  Just look at integers of the form $2r$, where $r$ is a positive prime such that $r \equiv -1\pmod{3}$.

If $n$ is an even number such that $n \equiv -1\pmod{3}$ and $n+9$ is not prime, then $n$ cannot be written as $p-q^2$, where $p,q$ are primes.  For example, you can take $n=30k-4$ for any positive integer $k$.

If $n$ is an even number such that $n \equiv +1\pmod{3}$ and $n-9$ is not prime, then $n$ cannot be written as $p^2-q$, where $p,q$ are primes.  For example, you can take $n=30k+4$ for any positive integer $k$.

Three conditions can simultaneously be satisfied.  For example, in the case of $226$ (or any number of the form $2(210k+113)$ such that $k$ is a nonnegative integer and $210k+113$ is prime), the $p^2-q$, $p^2-q^2$, and $p^3-q^3$ conditions hold.  In the case of $716$ (or any number of the form $4(210k+179)$ such that $k$ is a nonnegative integer and $210k+179$ is prime), the $p-q^2$, $p^2-q^2$, and $p^3-q^3$ conditions hold.  I don't know if there is any even number that satisfies all these four conditions, but my gut feeling tells me that it is impossible to find one.  In fact, I don't think that there is any number satisfying both the $p-q^2$ and the $p^2-q$ conditions simultaneously.